# How to access terragrunt variables in terraform code

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I have terragrunt config where have declared the variables using locals as below at root level. In the child module , have declared the child terragrunt config file called (terragrunt.hcl).
parent terragrunt file has following code :

```
locals {
  location = "East US"
}
```

child module terragrunt file has below code :

```
include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}

locals {
  myvars = read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("terragrunt.hcl"))
  location = local.myvars.locals.location
}
```

now, trying to access `location` variable in the terraform code (`main.tf`) using following code :

```
 location = "${var.location}"
```

but it throws error:

```
Error: Reference to undeclared input variable

  on main.tf line 13, in resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example":
  13:   location = "${var.location}"
```

Not getting how i can access variables defined in the terragrunt file in the terraform code . please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message means that your root module doesn't declare that it is expecting to be given a `location` value, and so you can't refer to it.

In your root Terraform module you can declare that you are expecting this variable by declaring it with a `variable` block, as the error message hints:

```
variable "location" {
  type = string
}
```

This declaration will then make it valid to refer to `var.location` elsewhere in the root module, and it will also cause Terraform to produce an error if you accidentally run it *without* providing a value for this `location` variable.

Comment: I am using terrgrunt. And i need this "location" variable to be defined in root terragrunt file and then refer it to the child module of terraform. can this be possible ? If yes, any example plz

Comment: I'm not familiar with Terragrunt, but it seems like [inputs](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/inputs/) is the feature for doing that.

Comment: Ok. Thanks ... i can make a use of inputs but now next question is , how to reference that in main.tf ? something like this : var.location (if location is defined in inputs ??)

Comment: The variable block I showed in my first answer is what will make `var.location` work in your root module, as long as you can configure Terragrunt to populate that variable with a value.